# Grouping several e-mails to one contact

Tags: sql-server, sql

My SQL skills are pretty low, so mind the basic level of my question...

I have a simple database where I have 2 distinct columns: CONTACTS and EMAILS

It kinda looks like this:

```
 CONTACT    |  E-MAIL COLUMN
 contact01  |  EMAIL #1 - contact01
 contact13  |  EMAIL #3 - contact13
 contact285 |  EMAIL #67 - contact285
 contact999 |  EMAIL #87 - contact01
```

How can I create 2 columns (one next to another) that will display the following:

```
NEWCONTACT  |  COMBO E-MAIL
contact01   |  EMAIL#1  /  EMAIL#87
contact13   |  E-MAIL#3
contact285  |  E-MAIL#67
```

NOTE: The "/" symbol on the second column can be whatever you wish.. 
I just need a separator (i.e. "+", "," , ";", etc...)

Comment: Are you asking for an ORDER BY?

Comment: How would I do that, in this case?
SELECT ContactList
From EmailColumn
ORDER BY contact.name;
? Ugh, sorry.. When I meant "basic level" I actually meant "zero to no experience"

Comment: `SELECT contacts,emails FROM yourTable ORDER BY SUBSTRING(contacts,8)`

Comment: Is this mysql or other?

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. I actually learned something.. Substring will come in handy in the future :)
P.S. - what does the "8" mean? After "contacts,"

Comment: Subtring just removes the first 7 characters from that column(it starts from 1) so now it orders just by the remaining numbers.http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/30619

Comment: Oops, I totally didn't put the whole information I meant too.. The same thing still applies, yes?

Comment: I don`t really get what you want.Clarify.

Comment: I meant that I didn't put all of the information in the main post.. Didn't specify the column titles and so on.
-This is for SQL Server 2008 (MS)
-Wow, that sqlfiddle is pretty awesome. Thanks mate :D

Comment: For sql server its bit different use `ORDER BY SUBSTRING(contacts,8,3)`

Comment: Thank you for your assistance :) . Really fast and clear!
(I suppose the ",3" is for selecting  what follows the previous deleted substring)

Comment: Why are you storing data this way? You list contact01 in the contact column and as a suffix of the e-mail column? This seems very problematic to me.

Answer (score 0):

The most difficult part of the whole thing is that you are grouping by part of your email column.  What appears to be the "real" contact.  If that isn't the case (if you have another column with a contact_id or something similar) then this can be simplified quite a bit.

```
WITH GroupingContact AS (
    SELECT Contact, SUBSTRING(eMail,1,charindex('-',eMail)-2) AS eMail,
            SUBSTRING(eMail,charindex('- ',eMail)+2,len(eMail)-charindex('- ',eMail)) 
                    AS GroupingContact
    FROM eMails)
SELECT MIN(Contact) AS Contact,
        STUFF((SELECT ', ' + GC.eMail
                FROM GroupingContact GC
                WHERE GroupingContact.GroupingContact = GC.GroupingContact
                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)')
            , 1, 2, '') AS eMailList
FROM GroupingContact
GROUP BY GroupingContact
```